# are array initializers syntactic sugar?

Tags: c, syntax

i'm writing some ocaml and realized that `[1;2;3]` is syntactic sugar for `1::2::3::[]`.

in the same vein, are array initializers in C also syntactic sugar?

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

the compiler must generate code to allocate and initialize those pieces of memory as desired.

where would the line be drawn between something the compiler actually compiles and syntactic sugar that stands for something else in a language?

Comment: Why are you asking? Is there any practical problem of which the solution depends on what is or isn't syntactic sugar?

Comment: "syntactic sugar" usually means a shortcut for something in the same language. @DavidRanieri

Answer (score 1):

It's syntactic sugar for declaring the array followed by assignments:

```
int a[3];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
```

In the case of a global array, the assignments should be put in the `main()` function, since you can't have assignments outside a function.

And in the case of a local static array, you'll need a static flag variable to indicate whether the array has been initialized, so you don't reinitialize it on every call.

```
static int a[3];
static bool a_init = false;
if (!a_init) {
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;
    a_init = true;
}
```

Note also that when you don't use an initialization list, you need to specify the array size explicitly.

Comment: Yes but `static a_init = false;` is syntactic sugar for what? (And in what language?)

Comment: In the case of a global array doesn't the compiler pre-initialize the memory to simply be loaded in when the program is run? Where is the distinction between "compilation" and "syntactic sugar"?

Comment: What matters is the result, not how it gets compiled. And a decent compiler should optimize what I wrote into the same pre-initialization.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I fixed the missing type.

Comment: OK but the first question remains.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I thought you were obliquely asking me what the invalid C syntax was. It's not syntactic sugar for anything, it's what the static variable initialization is sugar for.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it @Barmar . If yours is the "desugared" version (declare array followed by assignments), then why would the compiler optimize into pre-initialization when I already declared my global array as `int a[] = {1,2,3};`?

Comment: Because it can tell that it can simply copy those initial values into the array to implement the assignments, just like it would when compiling an initialization list.

Comment: Syntactic sugar is just about source code, not how it gets compiled. It allows you to express the same thing with shorter code.

Comment: "And a decent compiler should optimize what I wrote into the same pre-initialization." No it shouldn't, given that the array is `static`. Initialization vs assignment matters a lot. For example it is custom in embedded systems not to rely on static initialization since that could have occurred years ago if the system has been up and running. Instead you set the values in run-time using assignment before using the variable for the first time. A compiler optimizing that would break the program.

Comment: And then there's the even more obvious example why initialization != assignment, namely `const int a[3];`.

Comment: @Lundin If you wouldn't rely on static initialization then it doesn't really matter what it's equivalent to. But if you use it, it's effectively equivalent to what I wrote. The actual implementation might not need the boolean variable, so there's a minor difference in memory use.

Answer (score 0):

Array initializers could in some cases perhaps be called "syntactic sugar", in others they can't. It's not a formal term.

For example `a[]` could be said to be "syntactic sugar" in your example, instead of `a[3]`. Although for them to be equivalent, `a[] = {1,2,3}` has to be typed out, but in case of `a[3]` you could omit some initializers and still get an array of 3. So it turns a bit strange to call some form a convenient version of the other - they both allow shortcuts.

So in order to find out the about various valid syntax combinations, the answer will kind of have turn into an *"everything you wished to know about initializers (but were afraid to ask)"* one. All the dirty details are found in C17 6.7.9.

---

There are several equivalent ways of writing initializer lists. C got these somewhat intricate rules for initialization, which is based on a "current object" kept track of by the compiler. It initializes struct/arrays from the top to bottom. After initializing the current object, it makes the next on in the list the upcoming current object, and initializes members in that order.

So it only really cares about which array/struct/union member that corresponds to that current object, but is otherwise lax with brace placements. For example these are equivalents:

```c
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int arr[3];
} test_t;

test_t test1 = { 1,2,3,4 };
test_t test2 = { 1, {2,3,4} };
```

In either case the current object starts from `x` and then moves on to the array items, one at a time.

Though you can't really say that one form is "syntactic sugar" for the other - that the above works at all is because of a special rule, that in case of missing braces, the compiler is allowed to make do with what it got and use `2,3,4` to fill the array.

You could however say that `test_t test3 = { 1,2 };` is "syntactic sugar" for `test_t test3 = { 1,2,0,0 };`, since these are 100% equivalent. Elements not explicitly provided are filled in "as if the object had static storage duration", meaning filled with zeroes or null pointers.

Which allows these two 100% equivalent forms:

```c
test_t test4 = { 0 };
test_t test5 = { 0, {0,0,0} };
```

Here you could say that the former is "syntactic sugar" for the latter.

Similarly, all initializer lists may end with a `,` after the last item. So these are equivalent too:

```c
test_t test5 = { 0, {0,0,0} };
test_t test6 = { 0, {0,0,0,}, };
```

These trailing commas are handy for writing various macros.

And then of course there's the alternative syntax of *designated initializers*, which is also 100% compatible with the previous examples but self-documenting and explicit:

```c
test_t test7 = 
{ 
  .x = 1, 
  .arr = { [0]=2, [1]=3, [2]=4 } 
};
```

Here too, initialization works by a current object, though as we use designated initializers, we shift that current object. Meaning this won't work:

```c
test_t test8 = 
{ 
  .arr = { [0]=2, [1]=3, [2]=4 },
  5 // invalid
};
```

Here the current object is set to arr[0], then moves up. But there is no object in the struct after the array, so the extra initializer is invalid here. And `x` would be initialized to zero if not explicitly initialized.

Similarly, we could combine designated initializers with the classic style in all manner of gibberish combinations:

```c
test_t test9 = 
{ 
  .arr = { [1]=3, 4},
};
```

Here `x` is set to zero, as is `arr[0]`. `arr[1]` is set explicitly by designated initializer and becomes the current object, then `arr[2]` gets initialized to 4 as it becomes the next current object in the list.

So the overall syntax is very flexible but also kind of dangerous, if you forget to initialize items or end up initializing the wrong one by mistake.